# How to create Parametrized Operator

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, quantum-operation, quantum-circuit

How to transform the U3 gate of parameters (theta, phi, lambda) to an Operator. (in qiskit)
The following code don't work

```
theta = Parameter('theta')
phi   = Parameter('phi')
lamb  = Parameter('lam')

UO=Operator(UGate(theta,phi,lamb))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CircuitOp`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.CircuitOp.html) from Qiskit's [Operator Flow](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/operators/01_operator_flow.html):

```
from qiskit.opflow import CircuitOp

UO = CircuitOp(UGate(theta, phi, lamb))
```

You can use [`assign_parameters()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.CircuitOp.assign_parameters.html) method for parameter binding:

```
import numpy as np
op = UO.assign_parameters({theta: np.pi / 2, phi: 0, lamb: np.pi})

from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(op.to_matrix())
```

Comment: Thank you for helping!